# Why is my onActivityResult() always returning false?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up google sign in for my app but it keeps failing, I click on a button, get a popup, select account and a Toast pops up telling me that sign in failed. Any ways I can fix this? The problem lies in `onActivityResult()` method and the said Toast says "Auth went wrong". I've searched all over the internet but failed to find a solution or even a reason why this is happening. Line 80 is this 
`Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);`

```java
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 2;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Button btn_login;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    Switch();
                }
            }
        };

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(v -> signIn());
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w("TAG", "Google sign in failed", e);
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Auth went wrong :/", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(user);
                        Switch();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

```
2019-03-23 12:13:35.569 6312-6312/com.charpik.agropomocnik W/TAG: Google sign in failed
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.charpik.agropomocnik.SignInActivity.onActivityResult(SignInActivity.java:80)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7701)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: Have you correctly setup the Firebase Auth in your Firebase console? Usually the problem is happened because your app package name is different with the registered package name in Firebase console.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: @ALexMamo i added the error, and the line which causes it.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך the app package name and registered package names are the same, no mistakes there

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the similar issue by using the latest version of the appcompat library.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
```

If it's not the case, try without `requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))`. And if the error is not occurred, you should check the credential part again.

Check these:

- Is SHA-1 fingerprint correct?
- Is SHA-1 fingerprint for **debug** or **release**?
- Is package name correct?
- Did you use the **web application** type client ID?